# date function with oracle db

Tags: oracle, timestamp, to-date

While creating a table i have mentioned varchar2 type to store date , Now I am not sure about oracle query to retrieve "from to - to date " .

Till now i have tried this query

```
SELECT DSC_REF,EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, ACTION_DATE from DSC_UPLOAD 
WHERE ACTION_DATE Between (extract(month from to_date(ACTION_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')) = '02' 
                          (extract(month from to_date(ACTION_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')) = '03' 
AND extract(year from to_date(ACTION_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy'))='2018')
```

Comment: **Never** store dates in a `varchar` column. That is a **terrible** idea.

Comment: It's one thing if you have a legacy table but you definitely should not be creating a new table to store a date as VARCHAR2

Comment: Also, just FYI, I believe the `EXTRACT()` function returns a NUMBER not a CHAR.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ACTION_DATE` is of the `DATE` data type then a simple method is to just use `DATE` literals:

```
SELECT DSC_REF,
       EMP_NO,
       EMP_NAME,
       ACTION_DATE
from   DSC_UPLOAD 
WHERE  ACTION_DATE >= DATE '2018-02-01'
AND    ACTION_DATE <  DATE '2018-04-01'
```

If it is a string (why?) then:

```
SELECT DSC_REF,
       EMP_NO,
       EMP_NAME,
       ACTION_DATE
from   DSC_UPLOAD 
WHERE  TO_DATE( ACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) >= DATE '2018-02-01'
AND    TO_DATE( ACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) <  DATE '2018-04-01'
```

> is there any way to retrieve data only using month and year without mentioning date

You can do:

```
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM TO_DATE( ACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) ) IN ( 2, 3 )
AND    EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM TO_DATE( ACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) ) = 2018
```

---

Regarding your query, if `ACTION_DATE` is a `DATE` data type then:

```
to_date(ACTION_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Is a bad idea. `TO_DATE( date_string [, format_string [, nls_string] ] )` has a signature that takes between 1 and 3 string arguments. Oracle will try to be helpful and implicitly convert your date to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model and you end up with a query that is effectively:

```
TO_DATE(
  TO_CHAR(
    ACTION_DATE,
    (
      SELECT VALUE
      FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
      WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
    )
  ),
  'dd/mm/yyyy'
)
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not match `dd/mm/yyyy` then you will get an exception - and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so each user can modify it and it may not be consistent between users or even user sessions.

Comment: Error code 1843, SQL state 22008: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: I have tried this but am getting this error - Error code 1843, SQL state 22008: ORA-01843: not a valid month. Is there any other way to retrieve date from database and i have used varchar2 type for column.

Comment: @sujithraelumalai Updated.

Comment: Sir is there any way to retrieve data only using month and year without mentioning date

Comment: @sujithraelumalai Updated

Answer (score 0):

When your date string is always formatted as dd/mm/yyyy then one way to get month and year is:

```
 month = to_char(to_date(action_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'mm')
 year  = to_char(to_date(action_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'yyyy')
```

The syntax for between is:

```
expression BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Not sure what selection you are after given the example query.